# Cannot remove Packetfence - "Errors were encountered while processing: packetfence-redis-cache"

Tags: server, apt, package-management, software-installation

I had installed PacketFence on Ubuntu 12.04 Server Edition, and all was working fine.  I could access the dashboard at https://(ipaddress):1443 without issue.

After moving the hard drive into a different machine and verifying network connectivity, I could no longer access the dashboard at all.  After messing with it for a while, I figured it would be faster to simply remove it and reinstall since I had not gotten far in the configuration process yet.  After `sudo apt-get purge packetfence` and a reboot, I ran `sudo apt-get install packetfence` (sources and keys were already added the last time I installed).  Once that was complete, I ran `sudo service packetfence start`, which returned `packetfence: unrecognized service`.  Thinking that I must have overlooked some error message during the installation, I ran "sudo apt-get install packetfence" once again - below you can see the problematic output it returned:

```
administrator@PacketFence-ALTO:~$ sudo apt-get install packetfence
[sudo] password for administrator:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  sound-theme-freedesktop libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 gconf2-common libxfixes3 libxcomposite1 libcanberra-gtk3-0 dconf-g
  libdconf0 libxdamage1 libxi6 libvorbis0a libxcursor1 dconf-service libxrandr2 libgtk-3-common libogg0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  packetfence
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
263 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 74.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up packetfence-config (5.6.0) ...
chown: cannot access `/usr/local/pf/conf/pfconfig.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing packetfence-config (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up packetfence-redis-cache (5.6.0) ...
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/packetfence-redis-cache already exist.
 * Restarting packetfence-redis-cache packetfence-redis-cache
invoke-rc.d: initscript packetfence-redis-cache, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing packetfence-redis-cache (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packetfence-config
 packetfence-redis-cache
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was able to take care of packetfence-config by running `sudo apt-get remove --purge packetfence-config`, but `sudo apt-get remove --purge packetfence-redis-cache` (and virtually any other command I run, including `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`) returns the following:

`administrator@PacketFence-ALTO:~$ sudo dpkg --purge packetfence-redis-cache
(Reading database ... 84944 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing packetfence-redis-cache ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript packetfence-redis-cache, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing packetfence-redis-cache (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packetfence-redis-cache`

Aptitude has the following output:

```
administrator@PacketFence-ALTO:~$ sudo aptitude remove packetfence-redis-cache
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  init-system-helpers{u} libjemalloc1{u} packetfence-redis-cache redis-server{u} redis-tools{u}
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 1,662 kB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 114575 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing packetfence-redis-cache ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript packetfence-redis-cache, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing packetfence-redis-cache (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing redis-server ...
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Removing init-system-helpers ...
dpkg: warning: while removing init-system-helpers, directory '/var/lib/systemd' not empty so not removed.
Removing redis-tools ...
Removing libjemalloc1 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packetfence-redis-cache
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

Current status: 1 broken [+1].
```

Any ideas on how I can clear up the issues with the remaining packages associated with packetfence so that I can reinstall it from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be disregarded.  I was able to resolve it by doing the following:

`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info`

`sudo rm packetfence-redis-cache*`

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq packetfence-redis-cache`

After I issued these commands, I was able to successfully reinstall Packetfence using apt.